# Remote work on Mac OS X through Windows machine

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop

I have my developer Mac OS X machine at my work. And I have Windows machine at home. How could I work remotely on my Mac OS X machine through Windows machine which stay at home? I mean could someone advise me a good remote free or paid programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use VNC, awesome software and works cross-platform. VNC should be already available on the mac, simply enable it. On Windows you could use the free VNC-Viewer by RealVNC. Google is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ryan, I tried downloading realvnc from https://www.realvnc.com/products/select/macosx/windows/

I was able to get it running after following these steps:

Download VNC viewer for Windows ( I am using windows 10 lenovo laptop)
Download VNC Viewer and VNC Server for mac ( I was using Mac Mini in my case)
Both machines on same network.

Then, I had to go through minor configuration on Mac Mini when setting up VNC Server. I had to change the port. This was easy and took 2 minutes since the install wizard helps with this.

After installing on the mac and installing on the PC, the PC asked me for the server name. This is available in the "Diagnostics" tab of VNC server. (IP)

After you enter that into the PC, it shoudl prompt you for credentials, and your good. Hope this helps. :)

For me this entire task was to ensure I could launch XCode from PC laptop.